# IOS load jquery from local machine and use progressbar to load php file from server?

Tags: jquery, ios

trying to develop my first web based iphone app.

In order to make things faster, I want to load jquery from my local machine and when ready load my index.php on my webserver.

Is this possible? How?

Also, can I use a progress bar while the index.php is being loaded?

I would really appreciate a simple demo code, I'm a little bit lost here :-)

Thanks for help, I spent my two last days trying to make this :-(

Pluda

Answer (score 0):

Do you not have a webserver running on your local machine? If you're developing… you really should look into it. There's easy installs available or if your on a mac it comes bundled WITH apache.

ANYWAY, what you could do is have you index.html file load your local .js files and then with a site.js (or whatever) use the jquery .load() to load your .php file into a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page_container').load('http://www.yoururl.com/index.php');
});
```

And obviously there is a div with id="page_container" in your html.

Hope this gets you started (I don't recommend working like this though).

Comment: I do have a local webserver, but I want to load jquery from iphone itself (i've copyed it to my root application folder).